# Command to create even text lines through terminal

Tags: text, terminal, character, putty

I want to take a file with a variable amount of characters per line, and set it to 5 characters per line. How would I do so? Also, the last line does not have to be 5 characters long.

Also, the ordering of the text MUST BE IN ORDER. Meaning that the first 5 characters are truly the first five characters if you go from left to right, top to bottom.

Example

Text file before edit:

```
12345
123
123456
1234567890
12
123456
```

Text file after edit

```
12345
12312
34561
23456
78901
21234
56
```

I think this would basically break down to two commands. One command to remove all newlines so that all the text is in one line, and a second command to break the one line into lines 5 characters each.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: I am doing this through putty

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
tr -d \\n | fold -w 5
```